# Simple recovery or full recovery?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Today we had an issue with the log file; in three days it grew to 1.3TB (99.5% of the drive) and shrinking it became very difficult.

Anyways, I changed the recovery mode to `simple`, worked on the issue, prayed, and was able to shrink the log file.

Before changing back to `full`, I started reading up on it to see if it's actually necessary.

We back up the DB every day, and if anything happens, we can just restore to last night's copy. With that said, and considering the implications of the log file and the amount of processes that run per hour, I don't think it's necessary to set it back to full.

From what I've read, the only reason I would need full recovery is if I want to restore the DB past the last backup I have.

For example, let's say I have a backup from last night. If the database breaks now and it's set as 'simple', then I can only restore to what I have last night.

With 'full', I can use the log file to recover *stuff* that's not in last night's backup.

Does this make sense? If this is the case, then I think I can leave it as 'simple'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the case.

I'm betting your log file grew because you weren't backing them up. When you backup transaction logs, the log is automatically truncated. It's also truncated when a checkpoint occurs while in Simple Recovery Model. If you want to keep a full recovery model, then backup your transaction logs hourly, or every 30 minutes, or what ever your business requirements are OK with losing. That is, the question you should ask is **"How much data can I afford to lose"**. What ever this time is, that is how frequent your transaction logs should be backed up. If you are ok with losing an entire's day worth of data (potentially) then using a Simple Recovery Model would suffice.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Always a good idea to make sure all of your stakeholders are on board with whatever level of risk you take with the amount of data you could lose.  Seems if your log grew 1.3 TB in 3 days that you could lose a large amount of data in a one day loss.

Comment: @JM_ I doubt it grew that large in a day but simply hasn’t been truncated and shrunk, backed up, or had the server restarted in a very long time 